# Using pyaudio to Simulate Infrared Remote

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, infrared, hdmi

I'm trying to use pyaudio as a way to simulate the button press of an infrared remote. The IR receiver is connected to a 3.5mm jack, which I've connected to my Windows 10 machine and tried to record. The graphic below shows how the IR wire is normally connected to the HDMI splitter that I'm trying to simulate the button press on.

[image: Gist of HDMI splitter]

I'd like to swap out this IR in to 3.5mm wire with a USB to 3.5mm wire, and be able to 'play' the button presses over USB from a different device. Like I said, the 3.5mm end of the IR reciever is currently hooked into my Windows 10 machine and I'm using the following code to record it as a WAV, which from my understanding is lossless.

```py
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 4
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

just_changed = False

# record the audio
frames = []

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

print('Starting')
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
print('Ended')

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

I press the '1' button on the remote while pyaudio is recording, and when I play the file normally on my computer there's a small 'beep' sound when it was pressed, so I know it's being picked up. However, when I play the WAV over USB to the HDMI splitter it doesn't change to the input corresponding to the button I pressed.

Am I missing something? It feels like there should be an easier way to ingest and store the raw input from a 3.5mm.

NOTE: I've also tried to write a file with the raw data:

```py
file = open("output.raw", "wb")
file.write(b''.join(frames))
file.close()
```

But I haven't been able to find a good way to send that raw file over USB 'speaker' output.

If I were to guess I'd say it's something having to do with the sampling rate skipping over frames I need, but I don't know how to verify that.

Also if I'm completely turned around on this one please let me know.